# Spring RequestBodyAdvice is not picking up by the mock MVC frame work, how ever it is working for ResponseBodyAdvice

Tags: spring-mvc

We are using Spring 4.2.0-RELEASE and implementing `RequestBodyAdvice` and `ResponseBodyAdvice` advices to parse the request and response bodies.

When we try to write the mock unit tests using spring test frame work, it is picking up only the Response body advice and not reuqestBodyadvice

```
advices[0] = testRequestBodyAdvice;
advices[1] = testResponseBodyAdvice;
mockMvc =  MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(authTokenController).
  setControllerAdvice(advices).build();
```

Are we missing any thing here?